# Authentication with Google Play Games Unity plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to run the "Minimal" sample app in my Unity 4.3.4 setup. When i tap the "Authenticate" button; it stucked with the message "Authenticating...". I have this in the logcat;

> 03-26 02:47:40.758: W/dalvikvm(2410): DexOpt: method is in an
>   interface 03-26 02:47:40.758: I/dalvikvm(2410): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected,
>   referenced from method
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn
>   03-26 02:47:40.758: W/dalvikvm(2410): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 2445:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;.isConnected ()Z
>   03-26 02:47:40.758: W/dalvikvm(2410): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0010 03-26 02:47:40.758: W/dalvikvm(2410): VFY:  rejected
>   Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper;.beginUserInitiatedSignIn
>   ()V 03-26 02:47:40.758: W/dalvikvm(2410): Verifier rejected class
>   Lcom/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper; 03-26
>   02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410): AndroidJavaException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper 03-26 02:47:41.138:
>   I/Unity(2410):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410): 
>   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz,
>   IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject]
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0  03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject]
>   (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0  03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.FindClass (System.String name) [0x00000]
>   in :0  03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.*AndroidJavaObject (System.String
>   className, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>   03-26 02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject..ctor (System.String className,
>   System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0  03-26
>   02:47:41.138: I/Unity(2410):   at GooglePlayGames.A 03-26
>   02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410): NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object 03-26 02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410):
>   at
>   GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient+c*_AnonStorey0.<>m__1
>   () [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.148:
>   I/Unity(2410):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaRunnableProxy.run ()
>   [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410): 
>   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410):
>   Rethrow as TargetInvocationException:
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaRunnableProxy.run() 03-26 02:47:41.148:
>   I/Unity(2410):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String
>   methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>   03-26 02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName,
>   UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject[] javaArgs) [0x00000] in :0  03-26 02:47:41.148: I/Unity(2410):   at
>   UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMethod
>   (UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy proxy, IntPtr jmethodName, IntPtr jargs)
>   [0x00000] in :0

Any ideas?

Comment: are you including the android-support-v4.jar in your project? you can download it from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsupportv4jar.htm You may also need google-play-services.jar

Comment: @hades2510 how can i add these to my Unity project?

Comment: You should add them into the Assets/Plugin/Android folder and Unity will pick them up

Comment: Did this solve your issue? I am just experiencing the same...

Comment: No @habitoti. May be it's incompatible with the latest Android Support  Library.

Comment: Checkout a corresponding Github ticket, there is a solution now, and it works for me (and others): https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/81#issuecomment-39416697

Comment: the unfortunate reality is that all the PG plugins around are pretty much crappy. (sadly too unity's own apple gamecenter stuff is of course a joke.)

it's tough to have to pay if you're just a hobbyist, but the only real-world solution is to get the prime31 plugins, which work first time every time.